# DXA 2.2 Is there a best practice for language dependent texts without release?

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

This works.

added 2 fields in schema "Resource Custom"

1. "cookieMessage1" as text
2. "cookieMessage2" as text (occurs n).

Then "publish settings" and did show on cd server ..\BinaryData\ .json

```
{...
   "cookieMessage1": "U kunt deze {entity} niet bekijken",
   "cookieMessage2": "nl:Ga naar instellingen\r\nen:Goto settings\r\nde:Mein",
...}
```

Settings can be used in our webapp views.
Prefix e.g. "en" for English, "de" for German etc.

[image]

**Question:**
Is there a better way for language depend text to do it?

**Note:**

1. These texts are very general and therefore not bound to a component.
   you want to change such a text without release.
2. This solution is based (only English) text in ticket
   [DXA 1.7: Custom Configuration / Resource Schema](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/dxa-1-7-custom-configuration-resource-schema)

Comment: Are you using a single publication for multiple languages then? Any reason you cant use BluePrint to separate languages and then you can simply localise to provide translations. I'd says thats the more standard approach.